# Why is in when I change the height on this bit of CSS styling for a div from px to % it doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, css

In [this code](http://jsbin.com/azare/edit) (that uses jQuery), the following line in the html

```
#canvas { height: 500px; background: white; }
```

sets the height on the canvas to draw on. But if you change the height to a percentage value like this:

```
#canvas { height: 20%; background: white; }
```

the canvas doesn't display at all. Why is that? Thanks for reading.

Comment: When using percentages in CSS measurements, you should always ask yourself: x% of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the percentage doesn't work, then it simply means that the **parent** element doesn't have a height. In this case, you'd like to give both `html` and `body` a height.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Setting it on `body` only won't work since its height in turn depends on the `html` one.

See also [this revision](http://jsbin.com/azare/111) of your demo.

Answer (score 5):

I imagine it's because your canvas' containing div has no height value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use percent (%) if you put a parent with specific value.

See [my revision](http://jsbin.com/azare/108/edit).

There, I put a div parent with 300px of height. The canvas have 100% of this.

Answer (score 2):

The parent container needs to have a height - else the browser doesn't know what to calculate the height from. It's thinking...20% of what? Makes sense to us but not to it.